# Django : Storing user steps with django admin form

Tags: python, django, session

I am doing a workflow app that forces the users to go through a set of forms and save some data.
They can leave the process of filling that form and log-out at any point of time.
When they log in back, they should be redirected to the same form/page where they left last time.

What is the best way to approach this problem ? Should I have a model in this app which stores such data every step ?

**UPDATE:**
By form I mean admin forms.

Comment: django provides Wizard. You then need to store the state of the Wizard process when the user log out. And restore it when he will resume the process.

Comment: Does this also work for admin forms ?

Comment: i dont dont ; you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) is what you want.

You can use `SessionWizardView` for more easily display the wizard when user comes back again.

Comment: Let me update my question a bit. The forms would actually be admin forms, in the admin interface.

Comment: You can use the admin forms, but you will have to write url+view for this.

Comment: Django form wizard is broken